# value of optional type NSManagedObjectContext not unwrapped

Tags: swift

```
@IBAction func start(sender: UIButton)
{
    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as    AppDelegate)
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    var newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
    newUser.setValue(label!.text, forKey: "score")

    context.save(nil)

    startGame()
    startButton!.enabled = (startButton!.titleLabel!.text == "Start")
}
```

When i was using the NSManagedObjectContext, it said i need to unwrap the value, but when i did so, a fatal error popped up, "Found nil when unwrapping an optional value". I did not set the NSManagedObjectContext to be optional type. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should follow the latest Apple Xcode template and use an optional:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
   let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
   if coordinator == nil {
       return nil
   }
   var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
   managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
   return managedObjectContext
}()
```

and

```
let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
```